# qt designer and data bound controls?

Tags: database, qt4, designer

can I use QT Designer 4 to create / design tables or other controls with automatic binding to database connections?

Or must I write specific code for that in my application?

(i'm using python 2.5 with pyqt 4.8 on Windows xp, if it matters)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Qt supports this using the MVC model, but you need some code (not too much really) to make the Database connection and some settings of a QSqlTableModel, which can be later shown with a QTableView.